# Track time taken to scale up in Kubernetes using HPA and CA

Tags: kubernetes, monitoring, tracking, kubernetes-pod, hpa

I am trying to track and monitor, how much time does a pod take to come online/healthy/Running.

I am using EKS. And I have got HPA and cluster-autoscaler installed on  my cluster.

Let's say I have a deployment with `HorizontalPodAutoscaler` scaling policy with 70% `targetAverageUtilization`.
So whenever the average utilization of deployment will go beyond 70%, HPA will trigger to create new POD. Now, based on different factors, like if nodes are available or not, and if not is already available, then the image needs to be downloaded or is it present on cache, the scaling can take from few seconds to few minutes to come up.

I want to track this time/duration, every time the POD is scheduled, how much time does it take to come to `Running` state. Any suggestions?

Or any direction where I should be looking at.

I found this [Cluster Autoscaler Visibility Logs](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cluster-autoscaler-visibility), but this is only available in GCE.

I am looking for any solution, can be out-of-the-box integration, or raising events and storing them in some time-series DB or **scraping** data from Prometheus. But I couldn't find any solution for this till now.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing out of the box for this, you will need to build something yourself.

Comment: Any direction, where I should be looking at to build this?

Comment: Not really? You can use the API to watch event objects to monitor for scaling stuff from c-a and then try to correlate that with pods?

Comment: Overall, I’m not sure what measuring this would accomplish since it doesn’t help you optimize things particularly. Better to look at node start and pod start times independently and optimize them as separate problems.

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is get the pod metrics in the prometheus using the kube-prometheus-stack and monitor how much time it takes to get the pod in ready status using this query

kube_pod_status_ready_time{pod=~".*$pod.*"}-kube_pod_created{pod=~".*$pod.*"}

https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/blob/main/docs/pod-metrics.md